# SqlAlchemy - check type of mapped class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

lets say that I have an object called `obj` that I know is an instance of a mapped class for SqlAlchemy.

Is there a way to check which "model" it is mapped to?

Comment: Try `type(obj)`. If you need more detailed info, read on using SQLA introspection: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/inspection.html. Could you provide a bit more concrete example of what you're after, so that a proper answer can be formed.

Comment: this is what I was looking for! thank you